# Python Django Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/393/task/558'

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I receive this error. It is happening during regular requests from front end, previous request has response 200, but then my backend container is suddenly reloading. Previously it was working and everything worked well.

Django version 3.2.13
Python version 3.9
Cloud AWS

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 329, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 335, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 375, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 391, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 294, in watched_files
    yield from directory.glob(pattern)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1177, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 611, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 558, in _select_from
    with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/393/task/558'
```

This is requirements.txt:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
amqp==5.1.0
anyio==3.5.0
asgiref==3.5.0
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
autobahn==22.4.2
Automat==20.2.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
boto3==1.22.7
botocore==1.25.7
celery==5.2.6
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.4.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==8.1.2
click-didyoumean==0.3.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
colorama==0.4.4
constantly==15.1.0
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
cryptography==37.0.2
daphne==3.0.2
Deprecated==1.2.13
Django==3.2.13
django-celery-beat==2.2.1
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
django-debug-toolbar==3.2.4
django-filter==21.1
django-redis==5.2.0
django-ses==3.0.1
django-storages==1.13.1
django-timezone-field==4.2.3
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.1.0
drf-yasg2==1.19.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
h11==0.13.0
hiredis==2.0.0
httptools==0.4.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.3
incremental==21.3.0
inflection==0.5.1
itypes==1.2.0
Jinja2==3.1.1
jmespath==1.0.0
kombu==5.2.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
msgpack==1.0.3
numpy==1.22.4
openpyxl==3.0.10
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.2
prompt-toolkit==3.0.29
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.3.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.8
python-crontab==2.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.6
python-dotenv==0.20.0
pytz==2022.1
PyYAML==6.0
redis==4.2.2
requests==2.27.1
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
s3transfer==0.5.2
sentry-sdk==1.5.10
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
stripe==2.73.0
Twisted==22.4.0
txaio==22.2.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.9
uvicorn==0.17.6
uvloop==0.16.0
vine==5.0.0
watchgod==0.8.2
wcwidth==0.2.5
websockets==10.3
wrapt==1.14.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
yearfrac==0.4.7
openpyxl==3.0.10
Pillow==9.2.0
```

this is docker-compose file:

```
backend:
    image: backend:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: backend
    hostname: backend
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./media:/app/media
      - ./static:/app/static
    command: bash -c "ls -la && python -u manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python -u manage.py migrate && python -u manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Any thoughts and help?

Answer (score 0):

we had the same problem while upgrading our project to "django 4" and "python 3.8".

searching for several weeks for any possible solution, we found that our project is quite robust; it has a lot of files and django's default "auto-reload" is not optimal enough in these cases.

Consider installing **watchman** in your project

Docs:

- https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/01/20/efficient-reloading-in-djangos-runserver-with-watchman/
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver